# Determining a Closed Formula for the Positive Zeroes of the $n^{th}$ Derivatives of the Function $x↦x^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, differential-calculus

The derivatives of the function $ f(x)=x^{-x}$ have interesting properties, especially when looking at their roots. I am interested in studying the behavior of the roots of the derivatives as the order of the derivative increases. I would like to find a closed formula that can calculate the root of the $n^{th}$ derivative, however I am having a difficult time finding any noticeable patterns. The best I have found is

$ a_N=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left(\frac{(e-1)^n}{e\cdot n!} \right)  $

where $N$ is the order of the derivative. This produces the first two roots, which are $\frac{1}{e}$ and $1$, but fails for any $N>2$. I assume that the zeros of the higher order derivatives have some relationship to $e$ but don't know what that relationship is. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here are the roots of the 2nd derivative, per Maple: 1, exp(2*LambertW(-(1/2)*exp(1/2))-1)

Comment: That is an interesting result, I was thinking only about the positive real roots but looking at the complex roots might give me a better understanding of what is going on between the derivatives. What about the third derivative?

Comment: Here are the numerical roots for 1st 30 derivatives per Maple fsolve. Rather multi-nodal.
0.3678794412
1.
1.594172705
2.156081546
2.693037878
0.7698317570
0.8922004122
1.076132692
1.297019230
1.551075081
1.836655380
2.149997442
2.484434915
2.832475855
3.188064676
3.547210496
3.907546791
4.267731451
6.550697400
4.984984445
5.341414895
3.785444605
3.679466558
3.837551474
4.023299304
4.227416876
4.446526524
4.679075468
4.924146178
5.180922002

Comment: Very true, but is there anyway that an exact answer can be formulated. I know that some derivatives have more than one real root so in my studies I have focused on the larges root for each derivative. It may be that such a formulation doesn't exist; in which a proof would be accepted at an answer showing that it is impossible to find exact solutions.